# Best Way for OpenGLES 2.0 Android Horizontal Scroll to part of the GL Surface View

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, horizontal-scrolling

I am newbee to Android OpenGL 2.0. I would like to know the best way on how to implement Horizontal Scrolling to only Part of the View and Vertical Scrolling to complete View. I was able to achieve Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling to the complete View. If i have to Use Layers can you explain a bit more on how to achieve layers and draw shapes on those layers separately.

I tried using two different SurfaceViews it does not work. Here is my Code for Scrolling Horizontally.

@Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

```
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, mXOffset, mYOffset, -3, mXOffset, mYOffset, 0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

    mGraph.draw(mMVPMatrix);

    mLine.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    msquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you clarify what you mean by "part of the view" and "complete view"?  In general, you are in the right direction - you are best off either moving the coordinate system (Matrix.translateM for an android based implementation) or moving the camera which you have the code to do.  As you have mentioned this will move everything though.  You could send multiple model-view projection matrices into your vertex shader and then decide which to use based on the pixel location.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve though, so a little more detail would help me give better advice.

Comment: Thanks For the reply. I have to draw a dynamic graph with multiple lines parallel to  x-axis based on different Y-values and for each line i have 3 buttons which i have to draw with openGL. I was able to achieve until here. Now the task is when we scroll horizontally the buttons have to stay and the graph has to move left to right and when we scroll vertically the complete view meaning graph and buttons have to scroll.

Comment: Sure, I'd suggest to just compute 2 different model matrices - one for the buttons, and another for the graph elements.  When you draw then you'd just update the model matrix for the elements, computer MVP, then draw the graph parts then compute the model matrix for the buttons, recompute the MVP, and drawElements for the buttons.  This way you can move the axis separately from the buttons.